# MySQL connection doesn't work Ubuntu?

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I have installed lamp on Ubuntu and everything is working fine i tried `localhost/testphp()` that works fine but when I put that code it shows the values if i echo them but it doesnt insert them in the db and it doesnt give error on mysql connection either. 
using POST method to send form data

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST">

        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text"  name="name">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="pass">
      </form>
```

and here is the php code

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "hello I am here !<br/>";


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","login");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

    }



$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
echo " Name: ".$name." <br/>Password: ".$password; 
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO login_data (username, password) VALUES ('". $name ."', '". $password ."')");
//it doesnt insert the data 
//how do i check the error of that query ? 
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Help !

Comment: try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top so that you will get error on the page.Or `exit(" here ");` line by line.

Comment: You have a syntax error on the `$sql` declaration. Add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script to find out why.

Comment: i have added `ini_set('display_errors',1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of script and still the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO login_data(username,password) values(".$_POST['name'].",".$_POST['password'].")";
```

mysqli_query( `mysqli $link , string $query`)

First connection, then the query. And use `mysqli`

`$a=mysqli_query($con, $sql );`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can enable PHP errors with your php.ini with :

`display_errors = on`

Or by using a .htaccess file.

Then the sql may be :

`$sql = "INSERT INTO login_data(username, password) VALUES ('". $name ."', '". $password ."')";`

As Don said, you use mysqli and then mysql. You have to use mysqli_query();

Comment: i turned on the `display_errors = on` and its displaying the errors now but  `$sql = "INSERT INTO login_data(username, password) VALUES ('". $name ."', '". $password ."')";` that doesnt work

Comment: @RanaMuhammadWaqas And did you try without `'` ?. I mean: `$sql = "INSERT INTO login_data(username, password) VALUES (". $name .", ". $password .")";`

Comment: the username and password columns of you table login_data are strings right (varchar or something like that) ? If so you have to surround them by quotes in the query. Do you test the values of `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['pass']` ?

Comment: yes i have tested the values and it gives the values fine but it doesn't insert the values using ` $sql = "INSERT INTO login_data(username, password) VALUES ('". $name ."', '". $password ."')";` and no error

Comment: As Don said, you use mysqli and then mysql. You have to use mysqli_query();

Comment: k i used `mysqli_query();` and it solved the problem 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

your sql statement is incorrect :

```
$sql="Insert into login_data(username,password) values("$name","$password")";
```

It should be

```
$sql="Insert into login_data(username,password) values("'".$name."'","'".$password."'")";
```

since `$name` and `$password` are predefined, you just need to pass them with proper quotes.

Comment: passing the values in double quotes in your statement is terminating the sql statement in incorrect manner.

Comment: when i put used the `$sql="Insert into login_data(username,password) values('$name','$password')";` it gives the error `hello I am here
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in /var/www/form.php on line 23
test@tes.com 123
Could not insert data ! ` but when i use this `$sql="Insert into login_data(username,password) values("'".$name."'","'".$password."'")";` it gives no error and nothing inserted in table

Comment: add `echo "values : ".$name." ".$password; die();` to check the values of param before insert.

Comment: it gives the values of name and password when i added `echo "values : ".$name." ".$password; die();`

Comment: but that doesnt add any values to the DB why how to check it ?

Comment: okay, i think you created the query but didn't execute it as from what i can see from your code....add `$result = $mysqli->query($con,$sql);` and `echo the $result`...did this help???